# AsyncTask randomly stops

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a pull based app that has to pull from the Server every 15 seconds. For that I used a normal AsyncTask, my code basically looks like this:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
   while (true && this.pull_on ) {
     pull_data();
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15)
};
```

Now I have the massive Problem that, the app just stops pulling out of the blue. `No exeptions`, the Status of the AsyncTask is 'running' the 'pull_on' variable is set to 'true' but it just stops pulling.

I can `not reproduce` this, it just happens sometimes, I can work perfectly for a long time and then it just stops.

Does anybody have an idea how this can happen?

Should I refactor and implement this with a timer?

Also what benefit would using a Service have over what I do know? Battery-power is not an issue.

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I should add that sometimes I start Activitys form the AsyncTask. Like this 'ApplicationManager.getCurrentActivity().startActivity( myIntent )' but I does not seam to be a Problem.

P.P.S.

Timer seams to be to limited for what I want to use, I do want to do something every 15 seconds but in some special case I want to stop the the pinging and then restart it again. The amount of hacking for that seams to be more work then just doing it with a AsyncTask.

Comment: You can do a thread dump when the task stop pulling to see what's going on. And what are you doing in pull_data() ?

Comment: I get back a JSON, depending on what message I got back I either start a activity, update something in the database or if the app is in the background I creat a notification.

Answer (score 1):

That is a terrible design. You do not want to have an infinite loop on the background every 15 seconds. That will drain battery when the app is pushed to the background, as one of the main problems.

One proper way to do it is to have an Alarm and react to that. A timer is not a bad option either.

I suggest you look into moving this to a service, which is what it looks like

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface

It talks about long-running operations, but recurrent operations also make sense to be moved to a service.

Official documentation on Services is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Battery is not an issue since the App is for Drives and the have the phone plugged in. So you would suggest a timer in a service?

Comment: From their documentation: Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

Comment: I believe you can set up a Service with that infinite loop. Just be sure that the service is unbind and that the loop exits when the service is canceled / unbind.

Comment: What value provides the service? I dont see what I gain with a service.